# Is it possible to determine sides in a triangle given angle of median and opposite side length?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, median

**Questions**

In the triangle $ABC$ below we know the values of $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\vert BD\vert$ in addition to knowing that AD is the median in the triangle, i.e. $\vert BD\vert = \vert DC\vert$.

Is it possible to analytically determine the other side lengths, i.e. $\vert AB\vert$, $\vert AD \vert$ and $\vert AC \vert$? If no, why not? Is the solution ambiguous?

---

**My Approach**

Since none of the triangles have enough information on their own, I have tried to utilize that the triangles $ABD$ and $ADC$ have the same areas to give me some insigts about the relationship between them:

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{2} \vert AB \vert \vert AD\vert \sin(\alpha) = \frac{1}{2} \vert AD \vert \vert AC\vert \sin(\beta) 
\end{align*}
simplifying to
\begin{align} \vert AB \vert \sin(\alpha) =\vert AC\vert \sin(\beta) \qquad(1), \end{align}
or equivalently
$$\frac{\sin(\alpha)}{\sin(\beta)} = \frac{\vert AB\vert}{\vert AC\vert}\qquad (2).$$ This is convenient, since I can compute the ratio on the left hand side.

To gain more information about $\vert AB\vert$ and $\vert AC\vert$, I derive and expression for each of them using the sinus theorem on the triangles ABD and ABC, resulting in the two equations:
\begin{align}
\vert BD \vert &= \frac{\sin(\alpha)}{\sin(\delta)}\vert AB\vert \\
\vert BD \vert &= \frac{\sin(\beta)}{\sin(\zeta)}\vert AC\vert 
\end{align}
or in combination
\begin{align}
\frac{\vert AB\vert}{\vert AC \vert} = \frac{\sin(\beta)\sin(\delta)}{\sin(\alpha)\sin(\zeta)},
\end{align}
which can be substituted into Eq. (2) resulting in the relation
\begin{align}
\left(\frac{\sin(\alpha)}{\sin(\beta)} \right)^2=\frac{\sin(\delta)}{\sin(\zeta)},
\end{align}
or, when substituting $\delta = \pi - \zeta$
\begin{align}
\left(\frac{\sin(\alpha)}{\sin(\beta)} \right)^2=\frac{\sin(\pi - \zeta)}{\sin(\zeta)}.\qquad (3)
\end{align}
So when I go down this path my question becomes: Can I determine $\zeta$ analytically from Eq. (3)?

[image]

Comment: Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it? Don't worry if it's wrong - that's what we're here for. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959)'s a quick guide (if nothing else, read up the part on "[avoiding no-clue questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/#27933)").

Comment: $|AD|$ is the length of the segment $AD$. So $|AD|$ is not the median, $AD$ is the median.

Comment: Together with the relation you found (which you can also get by using the sine rule in $\Delta ACD$ and $\Delta ABD$), you have the cosine rule on $\Delta ABC$. Combining these will get you the other side lengths.

Comment: Since you know $AC \over AB$ you know $\sin{C} \over \sin{B}$. You also know $\sin(B+C)$. This should set up an equation where you can solve for the $B,C$ angles. After that the side lengths should be pretty trivial. However without computer aid this seems not so easy, as it seems to involve quartic terms after expanding. If you are looking for approximate numbers with help of say wolfram alpha, this method should be pretty good. But if you are trying to prove something by hand then this method is not good.

Comment: [This image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRrNv.png) Shows the triangle is unique.  Assume the point $C$ is above the side $AB$. Note that, for each point on the red circle we have the angle $\alpha$ and same goes for the blue one (still we only consider the point is above $AB$). So other than midpoint of $AB$ two circles intersect in only one point which implies the triangle is unique.

Comment: Thank you for your inputs! I have tried to elaborate on my approach and add a few more angles to the figure, to easier be able to describe the angles.

Comment: Be careful: from $(1)$ one gets $AB/AC=\sin\beta/\sin\alpha$. Moreover, $\sin\zeta=\sin\delta$, so your second relation gives nothing new.

Comment: From $${AD\over BD}={\sin\gamma\over\sin\alpha}={\sin\epsilon\over\sin\beta}$$ you can find $\gamma$, because $$\sin\epsilon=\sin(\alpha+\beta+\gamma).$$

Comment: @Intelligentipauca Does that not result in an equation very similar to Eq.(3), namely $$
\frac{\sin(\gamma)}{\sin(\alpha + \beta + \gamma)} = \frac{\sin(\alpha)}{\sin(\beta)},
$$
which can be solved numerically, but I am not sure if it's also possible to do it in an analytical way?

Comment: @Intelligentipauca ..and where do you get the identity $\sin(\epsilon) = \sin(\alpha + \beta + \gamma)$ from?

Comment: $\sin(\pi-x)=\sin x$ is a trig identity. $\epsilon=\pi-\alpha-\beta-\gamma$.

Comment: That trig equation is easy to solve: $$\tan\gamma={\sin\alpha\sin(\alpha+\beta)\over\sin\beta-\sin\alpha\cos(\alpha+\beta)}.$$

Comment: @Intelligentipauca Thank you, I know see what you mean! Do you have a reference for the last equation or a hint for how to derive it?
And do you want to write up an answer or should I do it?

Comment: I'm too lazy to write an answer. But that equation becomes a standard linear homogeneous equation in $\sin\gamma$ and $\cos\gamma$, after using [addition formulas](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrigonometricAdditionFormulas.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Answer based on @Intelligentipauca's comments)

Apply the sine theorem to both triangle ABD and ADC we get the two equations

\begin{align}
\frac{\vert AD\vert}{\vert BD\vert} &= \frac{\sin(\gamma)}{\sin(\alpha)} \\
\frac{\vert AD\vert}{\vert DC\vert} &= \frac{\sin(\epsilon)}{\sin(\beta)}.
\end{align}
Since $\vert BD\vert = \vert DC\vert$ we can combine the two equations to get

\begin{align}
\frac{\sin(\beta)}{\sin(\alpha)} = \frac{\sin(\epsilon)}{\sin(\gamma)}.
\end{align}

Utilizing the identity $\sin(x)=\sin(\pi-x)$ and that $\epsilon = \pi - \alpha - \beta - \gamma$ we get

\begin{align}
\frac{\sin(\beta)}{\sin(\alpha)} = \frac{\sin(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)}{\sin(\gamma)},
\end{align}
which has the solution
\begin{align}
\tan(\gamma) &= \frac{\sin(\alpha)\sin(\alpha+\beta)}{\sin(\beta)-\sin(\alpha)\cos(\alpha+\beta)}.
\end{align}
Knowing $\gamma$ the remaining values can be calculated using simple trigonometry.

Comment: You can accept your own answer if it satisfies the question.

Comment: It seems that I have to wait 2 days before being able to do so. Perhaps that is due to my low reputation.